# Kafka producer repeatedly throws 'Received invalid metadata error', how can I fix it permanently?

Tags: apache-kafka

```
[2023-05-22 12:30:45,398] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition collection_receipt due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderOrFollowerException: For requests intended only for the leader, this error indicates that the broker is not the current leader. For requests intended for any replica, this error indicates that the broker is not a replica of the topic partition.. Going to request metadata update now (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
```

Getting this error repeatedly and producer is not able to produce, how can i handle it automatically.

I took a restart for producer application and  deleted the topic and __consumer_offset then after it works fine but i need permanent fix for this

Comment: I have to delete the topic and __consumer_offset then after i works fine but how can i fix this.